# How to make a thread wait for object to completely destruct ? (Object is also having one thread)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-sleep

I am creating a gTEST wherein I started a service which is having its own thread. Before stopping the service I created object of the class which is having its own thread. Now I want the service thread to wait for the object to completely destruct (Class thread does it job and exits) and then stop the service thread. If  I am making the test sleep for sometime evrything is working well.

Test.cpp

```
    TEST_F(TestFixture, TestName) {

      service->start(); //Sevice is having its own thread

      // Creating the Object 
      DummyClass Obj(); //Object is having its own thread that starts on initialization 

      EXPECT_CALL(*_Mock,
                  Func(NotNull(), NotNull(), NotNull(), NotNull(), NotNull(), NotNull()))
          .Times(1)
          .WillRepeatedly(Return(1));
      EXPECT_EQ(true,
                Obj.Func1(a,b, c, d)
                    .IsOk());

      usleep(1000); //If I remove the this reason-111: Connection refused.
     service->Stop();
    }
```

Class.cpp

```
    //Destructor
    SasThreadHelper::~SasThreadHelper() {
    this->StopThread();
    }

//Called in Constructor
void SasThreadHelper::StartThread() {
  if (m_thread.get_id() != std::thread::id()) {
    return;
  }

  m_stop_thread_flag = 0;

  // spawn the thread
  m_thread = std::thread(&SasThreadHelper::ReadMessagesFromQueue, 
  this);
}

void SasThreadHelper::StopThread() {
  m_client_authenticated = 0;
  m_stop_sas_thread_flag = 1;
  m_thread.join();
}
```

Comment: Please, show us some code, preferably in the form of [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may also want to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). (Note that I didn't downvote. I don't like someone downvoting without explaining why).

Answer (score 0):

You can wait on thread execution with `join()`. If your test class joins own thread, you can wait in destructor to thread is finished like this:

```
class WaitOnOwnThread
{
    private:
        std::thread t;

    public:
        WaitOnOwnThread(): t{[](){
            std::cout << "Thread starts here" << std::endl;
            sleep(2); // thread is doing something
        }}
        {
        }

        ~WaitOnOwnThread()
        {
            t.join(); // wait that thread finishes
            std::cout << "Thread has finished" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    {
        WaitOnOwnThread w;
        std::cout << "Do some things in main thread" << std::endl;
    } // end of scope for destruction of WaitOnOwnThread

    std::cout << "end of main " << std::endl;
}
```